# Why didn't display icon in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, icons

I have been created subscribe form, using `php` and `jquery`.

Here is screen shot of submit form with icon http://s7.postimg.org/sxvtiyywb/Untitled_2_copy.png

```
<div id="newsletterform">
        <h3>Get Email Update</h3>
        <form action="send.php" method="post" id="newsletter" name="newsletter">
            <input type="text" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />
        <button id="actbtn" class="btn btn-7 btn-7h icon-envelope">Submit form</button>
            <span class="arrow"></span>
        </form>
       <div id="response"></div>
</div>
```

I works fine in localhost, but i have issue with display icons.

Here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/d0qmys0z/

I posted full code in jsfiddle link, There is not display icon, (message icon,error and success icons).

Only works fine, when i have a folder name "`Ajax-PHP-MySQL-Newsletter-master`"

Icon displayed only, when i run from this above folder name, otherwise didn't display icons.

May i know, what is my mistake?

I just confused, please can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your 'icon-envelope' class? (I didn't see it in the fiddle)

Comment: but it works fine, when i run in localhost..thanks

Comment: Do you know how to work with Chrome developer tool? can you inspect the element on local host to see it's css? then you will be able to see from where it's taking this class/path to icon

Comment: may i know, why it works fine, when the content located in this folder name "Ajax-PHP-MySQL-Newsletter-master" ? thanks

Comment: yes.. i checked, in that nothing to show in inspect element..

Comment: because maybe you have in this folder another css file which is included in your local host but not in the other place? you can try to look at the network tab (in chrome dev tool) and reload the page (F5)? do you see something with 404 (color red) in non-localhost ?

Comment: Yes i got it, after clear cookies, and run, it doesn't run.. so that, i added fonts. so after that it displayed icons.. thanks @italyB

Comment: I've added it below as my answer, I'll appreciate if you mark it as solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

because maybe you have in this folder another css file which is included in your local host but not in the other place? you can try to look at the network tab (in chrome dev tool) and reload the page (F5)? do you see something with 404 (color red) in non-localhost ?